# How do I tidy up my url after sending lots of information?

Tags: php, arrays, url, pagination

I am a beginner programmer/coder who is currently trying to get to grips with HTML and PHP. I currently have a locally hosted searchable database that (when used) brings up a list of the first twenty entries that correspond to your search terms, with buttons to send you to the next page, last page, etc. (you know... pages...) The search outputs information into the URL ([url]?q=Alphonse&f=Elric etc). I have two problems with this at the moment.

**Problem A:**
My URL contains information that is unused. If I don't put anything into the search term it simply comes out with "q=&x=&f=..." etc. This makes the URL absurdly long even on the most simple searches.

1. *Can this be cleaned up through just php?*
2. *Would this method be different if I end up hosting this online?*

**Problem B:**
The way my paging functions is to send the user to the following link `'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].'&pn='.$nextPage.'`. This outputs the current link but with "pn=1" at the end (Or whatever relevant page they click).

This method itself makes the URL quite messy. If they click through multiple pages, and perhaps go back and forth, the link ends up having "pn=1&pn=2&pn=3&pn=1...." etc at the end. I assume that this will be answered by the first query, but it is slightly different in that this is information that is actually present.

*How do I remove this superfluous information, and just keep the (final) relevant one?*

I am *thinking* that I can use parse_str to turn the URL into an array, then delete each entry of the array that are empty, then create a new string out of that array and make that the link the search/next page button goes to.

Does that sound like it would work? If so, how do I delete those specific array entries, and how would that array then be stored? Would the array lose those entries and calling a deleted entry "$array['1']" for example result in an error, or does deleting entries in an array move everything up one to fill the gap?

Apologies if I'm asking too many different things in one post here!

Comment: `Can this be cleaned up through just php?`...not really, unless you tell the browser to redirect. But why is it actually a problem? Lots of sophisticated, professional sites have "absurdly long" URLs in some circumstances - look at some Amazon links, just as as an example. Maybe employ a URL-shortener if you want to allow people to share these links in a compact format. Otherwise I'm not sure what the use-case is for caring about the aesthetic appearance of your URLs?

Comment: `Would this method be different if I end up hosting this online?`...your application's fundamental behaviour won't change just because you run it on a different server. I'm not really sure what you're expecting here.

Comment: `Does that sound like it would work?`...why don't you try it and see? There's no reason why not (although that's not to say that someone might think of a neater solution)

Comment: `how do I delete those specific array entries`...just remove everything that's `pn`? Or at least, ignore them when re-building the string.

Comment: `does deleting entries in an array move everything up one to fill the gap`...it's irrelevant, if you just use a `foreach` loop instead of `for`. But as I said above, you don't necessarily need to mess about deleting stuff from the array, just make the code read the contents of each entry and decide whether to actually use it in the new string or not.

Comment: `Apologies if I'm asking too many different things in one post here!`...yes that's a possibility. Posts are supposed to be focused on one main thing at a time. Your questions are all linked, but not necessarily all part of the the same overall request. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic